# log rotation inter-process lock failed opswork clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, logrotate, clockwork

I am using opswork with t2.medium machine with ruby clockwork running in it.

every 30 seconds we are triggering a job.

```
SPAWNED BG JOB FOR TASK: 20 for SC: 20 with Sidekiq id: 3afda705eaf597edb4bcc257
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
SPAWNED BG JOB FOR TASK: 25 for SC: 25 with Sidekiq id: f9142190bd44736815c10645
```

in clockwork logs i am seeing below error and clockwork functionally getting stopped. when i restart clockwork it is started working. i don't have any idea.

```
log rotation inter-process lock failed. No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - log/sql.log
```

help please

**Updated :**  few more information we are using ruby Logger to log messages in sql.log. it has a default log rotation option.  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394406/disable-logrotation-ruby-logger)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you were using regular logrotate then you need to use the copytruncate option ( https://gorails.com/guides/rotating-rails-production-logs-with-logrotate ). I'm guessing that the same principle applies here: copy the current log file, then empty the open, live one, so that the one Rails is attached to doesn't disappear.