# Disable logrotation ruby Logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, logrotate

I am using ruby Logger to log messages

```
logger = Logger.new('log/sql.log', 1, 500 * 1024 * 1024)
```

the age of file is 1 day and size of log file is 500MB. when it reaches 500MB, it will rotate log file and will keep 1 day age files.

i have already configured Linux log rotation using crontab for all log files. Now i want to completely disabled log rotation which is causing by  ruby Logger.

is there any way to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but did you try to pass 0 as second parameter?

Comment: `logger = Logger.new('logfile.log')` [Please refer docs for more info](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html).